# Can my creature spell be countered if I cast a split second spell after it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

Scenario:

1. I put 9 black mana into my mana pool
2. I cast [Massacre Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Massacre%20Wurm)
3. I cast [Sudden Spoiling](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sudden%20Spoiling)
4. I pass priority to my opponent

Sudden Spoiling has Split Second, which means that says players cannot cast spells or activate non-mana abilities while it is on the stack:

> Split second *(As long as this spell is on the stack, players can't cast spells or activate abilities that aren't mana abilities.)*

After Sudden Spoiling resolves, will players be able to interact with Massacre Wurm on the stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, the opponent can interact with the Massacre Wurm spell after Sudden Spoiling resolves.**

There is a round of priority (when players have the opportunity to take actions) both each time a player casts a spell or activates an ability, and also each time a single spell or ability resolves. The Split Second ability only prevents players from casting spells and activating non-mana abilities while the spell is on the stack. Once Sudden Spoiling resolves, it is no longer on the stack, so players can once again do those things.

Comment: Side note - the opponent can interact with massacre wurm even while a split second spell is on the stack, provided they don't cast any spells or activate any abilities to do so.  I'm not entirely sure how to engineer that yet

Comment: Voidmage Apprentice can do it.

Comment: I know nothing of MTG, so forgive me if this is a silly question, but does the opponent theoretically have the ability to counter-spell `Massacre Wurm` *before* OP cast `Sudden Spoiling`? What if OP puts down both cards at the same time, can the opponent "interject" their counter-spell "before" the `Sudden Spoiling`?

Comment: No. After casting a spell, the same player gets priority again, so they have the first opportunity to cast another spell.

Comment: So, to my mind, this implies that the *real* strategy is to wait for Massacre Wurm to resolve, and *then* cast Sudden Spoiling, after your opponent has already decided not to counterspell the Wurm.

Comment: The whole question here was about whether you could stop the opponent from countering the Wurm.

Comment: If you can somehow cast Massacre Wurm at instant speed, then you can prevent countering by casting Sudden Spoiling first, then Massacre Wurm, but that's going to be quite a bit harder to setup.

Comment: You can't cast Massacre Wurm if Sudden Spoiling is on the stack.